# Create jet colormap using blender gradient texture

Tags: texturing

I would like to know if there is anyway to create a texture for the jet colormap in blender. This colormap looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *ColorRamp* to calculate the spectrum.

1. Set the two border colors (Blue and Red)
2. Set *ColorRamp* node to *HSV > Far*
3. Add the *Gradient Texture* node

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is really niec. Now I not only know how to create, but also where it comes from :)

Comment: you can also control the number of levels and the RGB code of each level programmatically through Python.. meaning, you can port any matlab/matplotlib/custom colorbar if you get the RGB codes